# Make cursor unable to move through sprite pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So my question is simple: How do I make a sprite that my mouse can't pass through? I've been experimenting, and I found an unreliable way to do it that is also super glitchy. If anyone knows how I might go about this, please help.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
import pygame
import pyautogui
import sys
import time

pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
pygame.event.set_grab(True)
exit = False

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 100))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (200, 200)

    def collision(self):
        loc = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        yy = loc[1]
        xx = loc[0]
        if yy >= self.rect.top and yy <= self.rect.bottom and xx >= self.rect.left and xx <= self.rect.right:
            if xx >= 200: 
                pyautogui.move(216 - xx, 0)
            if xx <= 200: 
                pyautogui.move(-xx + 184, 0)            

w = Wall()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(w)
print(w.rect.top)
print(w.rect.bottom)
while (not exit):
    mouse_move = (0,0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                exit = True 
    w.collision()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    game_display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    clock.tick(30)
    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(game_display)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

note: please ignore my extra import statements, I am going to use them for later.

Comment: In what way is it "glitchy"?  The problem with the mouse is that if it is moved too fast it kind of "teleports" from one location to the next, and never exists in the in-between locations.

Comment: exactly. That is what the glitch is, it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want you have to check if the line form the previous mouse position to the new mouse position intersects the rectangle. Write a function `IntersectLineRec` which checks for the intersection and use it and returns a list of intersection points, sorted by the distance.
The function returns a list of tules whith points and distances:

e.g.

```py
[((215.0, 177.0), 12.0), ((185.0, 177.0), 42.0)]
```

```py
prev_loc = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def collision(self):

        global prev_loc

        loc = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        intersect = IntersectLineRec(prev_loc, loc, self.rect)
        prev_loc = loc

        if intersect:
            ip = [*intersect[0][0]]
            for i in range(2):
                tp = self.rect.center[i] if ip[i] == loc[i] else loc[i]
                ip[i] += -3 if ip[i] < tp else 3
            pyautogui.move(ip[0]-loc[0], ip[1]-loc[1])
            prev_loc = loc = ip
```

The function `IntersectLineRec` has to check if one of the 4 outer lines between the 4 corners of the rectangle inter sects the line between the mouse positions:

```py
def IntersectLineRec(p1, p2, rect):
    iL = [
        IntersectLineLine(p1, p2, rect.bottomleft, rect.bottomright),
        IntersectLineLine(p1, p2, rect.bottomright, rect.topright),
        IntersectLineLine(p1, p2, rect.topright, rect.topleft),
        IntersectLineLine(p1, p2, rect.topleft, rect.bottomleft) ]
    iDist = [(i[1], pygame.math.Vector2(i[1][0] - p1[0], i[1][1] - p1[1]).length()) for i in iL if i[0]]
    iDist.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])
    return iDist
```

`IntersectLineRec` checks if to endless lines, which are defined by to points are intersecting. Then it checks if the intersection point is in the rectangles which are defined by the each of the lines (the line is the diagonal of the rectangle):

```py
def IntersectLineLine(l1_p1, l1_p2, l2_p1, l2_p2):
    isect, xPt = IntersectEndlessLineLine(l1_p1, l1_p2, l2_p1, l2_p2)
    isect = isect and PtInRect(xPt, l1_p1, l1_p2) and PtInRect(xPt, l2_p1, l2_p2)
    return isect, xPt
```

To check if a point is in an axis aligned rectangle has to check if both coordinates of the point are in the range of the coordinates of the rectangle:

```py
def InRange(coord, range_s, range_e):
    if range_s < range_e:
        return coord >= range_s and coord <= range_e
    return coord >= range_e and coord <= range_s

def PtInRect(pt, lp1, lp2):
    return InRange(pt[0], lp1[0], lp2[0]) and InRange(pt[1], lp1[1], lp2[1])
```

The intersection of to endless lines can be calculated like this:

[image]

```
def IntersectEndlessLineLine(l1_p1, l1_p2, l2_p1, l2_p2):

    # calculate the line vectors and test if both lengths are > 0
    P = pygame.math.Vector2(*l1_p1)
    Q = pygame.math.Vector2(*l2_p1)
    line1 = pygame.math.Vector2(*l1_p2) - P
    line2 = pygame.math.Vector2(*l2_p2) - Q
    if line1.length() == 0 or line2.length() == 0:
        return (False, (0, 0))

    # check if the lines are not parallel
    R, S = (line1.normalize(), line2.normalize())
    dot_R_nvS = R.dot(pygame.math.Vector2(S[1], -S[0]))
    if abs(dot_R_nvS) < 0.001:
        return (False, (0, 0))

    # calculate the intersection point of the lines
    # t  =  dot(Q-P, (S.y, -S.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))
    # X  =  P + R * t
    ptVec = Q-P
    t = ptVec.dot(pygame.math.Vector2(S[1], -S[0])) / dot_R_nvS
    xPt = P + R * t
    return (True, (xPt[0], xPt[1]))
```

See the animation:

[image]

Comment: geez I didnt expect something so in depth like that. Thanks! I'll try it out to see how it works

Comment: Also, where do I put all these functions?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it, and it appears to work as before. Could you just give me the code for the sprite? that might work

Comment: Im going to try again though.

Comment: @RandomChannel Even more tricky than I thought, but It should work now.